# how to hide some specified affected version when creating an issue in jira?

Tags: jquery, jira, behavior

I use JIRA v6.1.3.

My project has some released version. eg. (V1.0 , V1.0.1 , V1.0.2 , V1.0.3, V1.1 , V1.1.1 , V1.1.2 )

I need to hide V1.0 to V1.1.1 when people create an issue.

And why I don't choose to archive V1.0 to V1.1.1  versions,is that archived versions related issues can not be searched in issue navigator.

I tried to use AJS in Behaviours Plugin

```
FormField versions = getFieldById("versions")
FormField desc = getFieldById("description")
if(getActionName()!=null && getActionName()=="Create Issue"){
desc.setFormValue("create screen:"+getActionName()+versions.getValue())
versions.setHelpText("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\
 AJS.\$(\"#versions optgroup\").each(function() { \
 AJS.\$(\"#environment\").val(\"22\"+AJS.\$(this).attr('label'));\
 if (AJS.\$(this).attr('label')==\"Released Versions\"){ \
 AJS.\$(\"#environment\").val(\"333\");\
 AJS.\$(this).find('option').each(function() {AJS.\$(this).hide();});\
 }\
 });\
 </script>")
}
```

but

```
AJS.\$(this).find('option').each(function() {AJS.\$(this).hide();});\
```

this code didn't work.
so I wrote the wrong hide() code ?

Answer (score 0):

I use below code as temporary resolution.
input js code into affect versions filed's description.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// on create issue screen ,remove released versions.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var createScreen=document.getElementById('create-issue-submit');
    removeOption();
    JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e,context) {
    removeOption();
    });
    function removeOption(){
        if(createScreen !=null && createScreen.value == "Create"){
            $("#versions optgroup").each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('label')=="Released Versions"){
                    $(this).find('option').each(function(){$(this).remove();});
              }
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```